# How do you make opportunities go through each stage of the sales cycle sequentially (no skipping stages), but allow regression

Tags: validation-rule, opportunity

I've followed the advise on other threads to use the following formula, but it isn't working for me - it is preventing any movement.

```
AND(
    $Profile.Name <> "System Administrator",
    ISCHANGED(StageName),
    TEXT(StageName) <> "Closed - Lost",
    TEXT(StageName) <> "Dead",
    CASE(
        StageName,
        "Stage 1 - Qualification", 1,
        "Stage 2 - Call", 2,
        "Stage 3 - Pitched and Emailed", 3,
        "Stage 4 - Advertisement Only, Negotiation", 4,
        "Stage 5 - Negotiation, Awaiting Signed Contract", 5,
        "Closed - Won", 6,
        0
    ) <>
    CASE(
        PRIORVALUE(StageName),
        "Stage 1 - Qualification", 1,
        "Stage 2 - Call", 2,
        "Stage 3 - Pitched and Emailed", 3,
        "Stage 4 - Advertisement Only, Negotiation", 4,
        "Stage 5 - Negotiation, Awaiting Signed Contract", 5,
        "Closed - Won", 6,
        0
    )
    + 1
)
```

Comment: I think the only way this could happen is if both of the `CASE()` functions returned the default value. You should double check to make sure that the StageName values in your formula are correct (and comparisons in formulas are case-sensitive).